Visual Studio Code: eperm operation not permitted , stat'd\System Volume Information' Problem
I am new to Vscode and learning HTML and CSS. Currently, while writing, this error is showing.
eperm operation not permited , stat'd\System Volume Information'
How to fix this?
I tried Npm error fix through terminal, but it does not exist in my laptop [HP pavillion-14]. If anyone could tell me how to fix this error.

NPM need to be installed. Try this... rename extensions.json in .vscode folder and then restart VSCode.
